# Facebook insights API: missing field in responses

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm using the Facebook insights API, but I'm missing **inline_link_clicks** in some of the responses (although the field does exist in others for the same account). Also, the API does not fail while requesting such a report and the response does have other requested fields populated.

I'm suspicious that this might be a correct behavior in case the inline_link_clicks are 0 but I could not find any such mention in the [Facebook API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v17.0)

Has anyone faced the same issue or could you point me to docs where this behavior is described in more detail?